# Printing a from a new window in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a new window, which contains html code from a file, and then print the document

The following code works, ie the layout shows within the new window, however the printed document is always blank

```
var FPrint = window.open('layout.php','','left=100,top=10,width=700,height=900');
FPrint.document.close();
FPrint.focus();
FPrint.print();
FPrint.close();
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Is anyone able to provide a suggested fix

Thanks

Comment: What's with the `FPrint.document.close()` bit before the printing?  Your JS isn't going to wait for the page to load, by the way - so it's possible it's getting to .print() before the DOM is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the document to finish loading before you can operate on the document.  I would suggest this:

```
var FPrint = window.open('layout.php','','left=100,top=10,width=700,height=900');
FPrint.addEventListener("load", function() {
    FPrint.print();
    FPrint.close();    
});
```

This assumes that the `.print()` method is synchronous and does not return until the printing is done (something I'm not sure of).  If it turns out to be asynchronous, then you may have to listen for the onafterprint event to know when it's done printing and only close the window at that time.

---

After a little testing, it is kind of a pain to close the window after it prints because IE behaves differently than Firefox and Chrome.  In Firefox and Chrome, the `.print()` method blocks and the next line of code does not execute until after the printing is done.  In IE, `.print()` is asynchronous and does not block so the next line of code executes immediately.  That obviously won't work with your `FPrint.close()` line of code since you will be closing the window before it has printed.  It appears that in IE only, you need to listen to the onafterprint event and close the window when that event fires.

Comment: Good Job - Works a dream - Thank you !

Comment: @stephen59 - make sure you test in IE because per the comments I recently added to my answer, there are complications in IE.

Comment: Thanks for you suggested check, I have cecked with IE 11 and it seems the windows print dialog box doesn't apear....Ive researched this a little and found FPrint.print() should be replaced with FPrint.window.print() for IE...do you concure ??....this works OK with FF however with IE is still doesn't apear.

Comment: @stephen59 - `FPPrint` is already the window handle to there's no use for `FPPrint.window`.  The issue is that in IE, `window.print()` is asynchronous so you are closing the window before the dialog event gets up.  I don't know yet how to solve in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `FPrint.document.close()` in the code.

Your javascript isn't going to wait for the window's DOM/document to fully load before stepping into `.focus()` and `.print()` -- so you might want to add promises.   If you're using jQuery at all, you can use it's `when`.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/